# how to rotate texture of the softball in box2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I have made softball body by following this link: http://www.uchidacoonga.com/2012/04/soft-body-physics-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-part-44/

now i want to rotate ball's texture to show the ball rotating.

How can i rotate the texture of it?

i have refer this link:http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/soft-body-chipmunk-physics/page/2/

But it's for chipmunk. i want to rotate texture in box2d.
any idea or suggestions are appreciated.

I have tried this

```
- (void) draw {
          if(draw){

              [self swap];

               printf("%d\n",R);
              for(int i=0;i<NUM_SEGMENTS+2;i++)
              {   

                  if((i+R)%12<=R && R<=12){
                      printf("%d--->%d\n",i,(i+R+1)%12);
                      triangleFanPos[i]=triangleFanPos[(i+R+1)%12];
                       textCoords[i] = textCoords[(i+R+1)%12];
              }else{
                  printf("%d--->%d\n",i,(i+R+1)%12);
                triangleFanPos[i]=triangleFanPos[(i+R+1)%12];
                   textCoords[i] = textCoords[(i+R+1)%12];
              }

          }
          if(R==12){
              R=0;
          }
        triangleFanPos[NUM_SEGMENTS+1]=triangleFanPos[1];
        textCoords[NUM_SEGMENTS+1]=textCoords[1];  


    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [texture name]);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, textCoords);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, triangleFanPos);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, NUM_SEGMENTS+2);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

}
```

& in my swap method i recalculate triangleFanPos & textCoords

```
-(void)swap
{
    printf("Recalculation Starts\n");   
    triangleFanPos[0] = Vertex2DMake(innerCircleBody->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO - self.position.x, 
                                     innerCircleBody->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO - self.position.y);
    Fanposition[0]=triangleFanPos[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SEGMENTS; i++) 
    {

        b2Body *currentBody = (b2Body*)[[bodies objectAtIndex:i] pointerValue];
        Vertex2D pos = Vertex2DMake(currentBody->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO - self.position.x, 
                                    currentBody->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO - self.position.y);
        triangleFanPos[i+1] = Vertex2DMake(pos.x, pos.y);
        Fanposition[i+1]=triangleFanPos[i+1];




    }
    triangleFanPos[NUM_SEGMENTS+1] = triangleFanPos[1];
    Fanposition[NUM_SEGMENTS+1]=triangleFanPos[NUM_SEGMENTS+1];
    textCoords[0] = Vertex2DMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SEGMENTS; i++) {
        GLfloat theta = ( self.rotation * M_PI / 180 ) + ( deltaAngle * i );
        textCoords[i+1] = Vertex2DMake(0.5+cosf(theta)*0.5, 
                                       0.5+sinf(theta)*0.5);

    }
    textCoords[NUM_SEGMENTS+1] = textCoords[1];

   R++;
    printf("Recalcutation ended\n");
}
```

now, texture goes with ball but i want to show that texture as rotating also 
What should I have to update here? 
Guide me.....

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code it just that you need to tell box2d to make a simulation step every frame update :

```
b2world->Step(dt, 10, 10);
```

`b2World` is the box2d world object used when creating box2d bodies. Call this step method in an update method scheduled somewhere in your main game scene/layer. `dt` is the time delta from the last update call that has passed until the current update call.

This method calculates the new position/angle of all box2d objects taking into account all the forces that act upon these bodies. You can read more about it [here](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082976)

And of course something in your physics world must make your ball rotate or otherwise there is no reason for it to rotate.

But nevertheless to make the ball's texture rotate with the ball you take the ball body's angle and apply it on the ball's node object :

```
self.rotation = -1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(innerCircleBody->GetAngle());
```

(`self` is the ball's node instance.)

There is a [great site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/28602/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial-bouncing-balls) with a nice tutorial about box2d and cocos2d which I recommend you to look through. It will help with understanding about this all updating stuff very easily.

Comment: I have updated world in my tick method as u told like               int32 velocityIterations = 10;
int32 positionIterations = 10;
world->Step(dt,velocityIterations,positionIterations);                
node.rotation=node->innerCircleBody->GetAngle();                     still it not affecting to my softball or it's texture...

Comment: I updated the angle calculation... forgot to convert it from radians to degrees (node rotation is in degrees units). Tell me if it works for you now ...

Comment: hey it's still not working,i want to rotate texture of the softball so that i can show that ball is rotating at it's place.I have attach link in my question in which they show it in chipmunk & right now i am not getting idea how to do it with box2d....any other suggestions if u can give will be helpful for me.

Comment: I have shifted trianglefanposition & textcoord position in draw method texture rotates well but when i move my softball texture is not moving with body........ Have you any idea?, how can i achieve this?.......@giorashc

Comment: @KomalShah can you post the relevant code after you updated it ? include texture creation and drawing

Answer (score 0):

This code is most common for making textures move and rotate with bodies

```
-(void)tick:(ccTime)dt{

int32 velocityIterations = 8;
int32 positionIterations = 1;
uint substeps = 4;
float32 subdt = dt / substeps;

for (uint i = 0; i < substeps; i++) {


    world->Step(subdt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);

for (b2Body* b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
{
    if (((CCSprite*)b->GetUserData()) != nil) {

        CCSprite *myActor = (CCSprite*)b->GetUserData();
        myActor.position = CGPointMake( b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
        myActor.rotation = -1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle());
 }
}
```

Hope it helps